# SSIS Package Variables

Tags: variables, ssis, integer

I have a bunch of different variables, most are strings, however I have one which is an integer. I need to grab this int from a table (where it is also of type INT). My problem is with setting the parameter for this variable. All my other variables (which are strings) i can use parameters like {0}, {1}, {2}..etc however Int32 Variables will not let me give it a value which is a parameter, how do I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

We store variables in a configuration table and that way they are set at run-time from the configuration for that server. We also sometimes run parent child pacakgae so the varaible can be differnt for differnt clients running the same process. Then the varaible is passed to the child paackge from the parent package in a parant package varaible.

Alternatively, you can run an execute SQL task at the start of the process to grab the value from the table and set it to the int variable in the result set. This is often the best way if the variable will change over time and thus you don't want it to be part of the configuration.